# How to assign coordinates to the elements of a flat metric space

Tags: mathematical-physics, geometry, coordinate-systems

Consider the [metric space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Definition) $(M, d \,)$ where set $M$ contains sufficiently many (at least five) distinct elements,
and consider the assignment $c_f$ of coordinates to (the elements of) set $M$,

$c_f \, : \, M \leftrightarrow {\mathbb{R}}^3; \, c_f[ P ] := \{ x_P, y_P, z_P \}$

such that distinct coordinates values are assigned to distinct elements of set $M$, and
such that for the function

$f \, : \, ({\mathbb{R}}^3 \times {\mathbb{R}}^3) \rightarrow {\mathbb{R}};$
$f[ \{ x_P, y_P, z_P \}, \{ x_Q, y_Q, z_Q \} ] :=  $
${\sqrt{ (x_Q - x_P)^2 + (y_Q - y_P)^2 + (z_Q - z_P)^2 }} \equiv {\sqrt{ \sum_{ k \in \{ x \, y \, z \} } (k_Q - k_P)^2 }}$

and for any three distinct elements $A$, $B$, and $J$ $\in M$ holds

$f[ c_f[ A ], c_f[ J ] ] \, d[ B, J ] = f[ c_f[ B ], c_f[ J ] ] \, d[ A, J ]$.

Is the metric space $(M, d \,)$ therefore flat?

(i.e. in the sense of vanishing [Cayley-Menger determinants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley-Menger_determinants) of distance ratios between any five elements of set $M$.)

Comment: This probably belongs on math.se or even on mathoverflow.

Comment: Aren't coordinates being used in physics; thus requiring a physics-based definition?

Comment: They are. But addition is also used in physics and that doesn't make it more physics than math. Your question is purely mathematical (geometrical, at that) in nature, I think.

Comment: I admit that the physics import of my question is subtle, namely to point out that determining and considering distance ratios is paramount and indispensible for characterizing a metric space (such as determining possible flatness, or evaluating curvature) while any assignment of coordinates is at best secondary. Surely there are various ways of putting this point (more or less) in the required form of a question. I hope to still do better myself; for instance generalizing from $\kappa = 0$ (flatness) to any value $\kappa$; eventually asking ...

Comment: ... under which conditions the assignment of coordinate-tuples is sufficient for establishing that a given metric space constitutes a manifold. 

p.s. "_addition is also used in physics and that doesn't make it more physics than math_" Right, per se. However, it remains to define what to add; or whether to use any other operation instead. 

p.p.s. Gotta go, look up again whether/how subtraction is defined for Dirichlet cuts ...

Comment: ... should have been _Dedekind_ cuts, of course.

Comment: See also the [metric for hyperbolic space](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-Klein-HilbertMetric.html) to get ideas.

Comment: @ja72: "_ [...] to get ideas._" -- The **one idea** of my question and readily provided answer below I'd express thus: Assigning coordinates $c_f$ to "principal identifiable points" (cmp. MTW box 13.1) and expressing distances (or at least distance ratios) in terms of such coordinates as $f$ is **subsequent to the physical** determination of distance values $d$ (or at least values of distance ratios). This applies to a flat metric space (with vanishing Cayley-Menger determinant) as well as to generalizations (such as vanishing Gram determinant with parameter $\kappa$; or quasi-metric spaces.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes -- if the coordinates (real number triples) $c_f$ can be assigend to the elements of set $M$ as required in the statement of the question, given the distances (ratios) $d$ and function $f$ as described above then the metric space $(M, d \,)$ is flat.

Because: for any fifteen (real) numbers, $\{ x_\alpha, y_\alpha, z_\alpha \}$, $\{ x_\beta, y_\beta, z_\beta \}$, $\{ x_\gamma, y_\gamma, z_\gamma \}$, $\{ x_\phi, y_\phi, z_\phi \}$ and $\{ x_\lambda, y_\lambda, z_\lambda \}$ the following determinant vanishes

0 = $  \begin{array}{|cccccc|}
  0 & {\small{\sum\limits_{ k \in \{ x \, y \, z \} } (k_\alpha - k_\beta)^2}} & {\small{\sum\limits_{ k \in \{ x \, y \, z \} } (k_\alpha - k_\gamma)^2}} & {\small{\sum\limits_{ k \in \{ x \, y \, z \} } (k_\alpha - k_\phi)^2}} & {\small{\sum\limits_{ k \in \{ x \, y \, z \} } (k_\alpha - k_\lambda)^2}} & 1 & \\
  {\small{\sum\limits_{ k \in \{ x \, y \, z \} } (k_\beta - k_\alpha)^2}} & 0 & {\small{\sum\limits_{ k \in \{ x \, y \, z \} } (k_\beta - k_\gamma)^2}} & {\small{\sum\limits_{ k \in \{ x \, y \, z \} } (k_\beta - k_\phi)^2}} & {\small{\sum\limits_{ k \in \{ x \, y \, z \} } (k_\beta - k_\lambda)^2}} & 1 & \\
  {\small{\sum\limits_{ k \in \{ x \, y \, z \} } (k_\gamma - k_\alpha)^2}} & {\small{\sum\limits_{ k \in \{ x \, y \, z \} } (k_\gamma - k_\beta)^2}} & 0 & {\small{\sum\limits_{ k \in \{ x \, y \, z \} } (k_\gamma - k_\phi)^2}} & {\small{\sum\limits_{ k \in \{ x \, y \, z \} } (k_\gamma - k_\lambda)^2}} & 1 & \\
  {\small{\sum\limits_{ k \in \{ x \, y \, z \} } (k_\phi - k_\alpha)^2}} & {\small{\sum\limits_{ k \in \{ x \, y \, z \} } (k_\phi - k_\beta)^2}} & {\small{\sum\limits_{ k \in \{ x \, y \, z \} } (k_\phi - k_\gamma)^2}} & 0 & {\small{\sum\limits_{ k \in \{ x \, y \, z \} } (k_\phi - k_\lambda)^2}} & 1 & \\
  {\small{\sum\limits_{ k \in \{ x \, y \, z \} } (k_\lambda - k_\alpha)^2}} & {\small{\sum\limits_{ k \in \{ x \, y \, z \} } (k_\lambda - k_\beta)^2}} & {\small{\sum\limits_{ k \in \{ x \, y \, z \} } (k_\lambda - k_\gamma)^2}} & {\small{\sum\limits_{ k \in \{ x \, y \, z \} } (k_\lambda - k_\phi)^2}} & 0 & 1 & \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \end{array}$.

Consequently, for any five distinct elements $A$, $B$, $J$, $K$ and $Q$ $\in M$ holds

0 = $ \begin{array}{|cccccc|}
  0 & \left(\frac{f[ c_f[ A ], c_f[ B ] ]}{f[ c_f[ A ], c_f[ B ] ]}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{f[ c_f[ A ], c_f[ J ] ]}{f[ c_f[ A ], c_f[ B ] ]}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{f[ c_f[ A ], c_f[ K ] ]}{f[ c_f[ A ], c_f[ B ] ]}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{f[ c_f[ A ], c_f[ Q ] ]}{f[ c_f[ A ], c_f[ B ] ]}\right)^2 & 1 & \\
  \left(\frac{f[ c_f[ B ], c_f[ A ] ]}{f[ c_f[ A ], c_f[ B ] ]}\right)^2 & 0 & \left(\frac{f[ c_f[ B ], c_f[ J ] ]}{f[ c_f[ A ], c_f[ B ] ]}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{f[ c_f[ B ], c_f[ K ] ]}{f[ c_f[ A ], c_f[ B ] ]}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{f[ c_f[ B ], c_f[ Q ] ]}{f[ c_f[ A ], c_f[ B ] ]}\right)^2 & 1 & \\
  \left(\frac{f[ c_f[ J ], c_f[ A ] ]}{f[ c_f[ A ], c_f[ B ] ]}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{f[ c_f[ J ], c_f[ B ] ]}{f[ c_f[ A ], c_f[ B ] ]}\right)^2 & 0 & \left(\frac{f[ c_f[ J ], c_f[ K ] ]}{f[ c_f[ A ], c_f[ B ] ]}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{f[ c_f[ J ], c_f[ Q ] ]}{f[ c_f[ A ], c_f[ B ] ]}\right)^2 & 1 & \\
  \left(\frac{f[ c_f[ K ], c_f[ A ] ]}{f[ c_f[ A ], c_f[ B ] ]}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{f[ c_f[ K ], c_f[ B ] ]}{f[ c_f[ A ], c_f[ B ] ]}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{f[ c_f[ K ], c_f[ J ] ]}{f[ c_f[ A ], c_f[ B ] ]}\right)^2 & 0 & \left(\frac{f[ c_f[ K ], c_f[ Q ] ]}{f[ c_f[ A ], c_f[ B ] ]}\right)^2 & 1 & \\
  \left(\frac{f[ c_f[ Q ], c_f[ A ] ]}{f[ c_f[ A ], c_f[ B ] ]}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{f[ c_f[ Q ], c_f[ B ] ]}{f[ c_f[ A ], c_f[ B ] ]}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{f[ c_f[ Q ], c_f[ J ] ]}{f[ c_f[ A ], c_f[ B ] ]}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{f[ c_f[ Q ], c_f[ K ] ]}{f[ c_f[ A ], c_f[ B ] ]}\right)^2 & 0 & 1 & \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \end{array}$;

and therefore also

0 = $ \begin{array}{|cccccc|}
  0 & \left(\frac{d[ A, B ]}{d[ A, B ]}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{d[ A, J ]}{d[ A, B ]}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{d[ A, K ]}{d[ A, B ]}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{d[ A, Q ]}{d[ A, B ]}\right)^2 & 1 & \\
  \left(\frac{d[ B, A ]}{d[ A, B ]}\right)^2 & 0 & \left(\frac{d[ B, J ]}{d[ A, B ]}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{d[ B, K ]}{d[ A, B ]}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{d[ B, Q ]}{d[ A, B ]}\right)^2 & 1 & \\
  \left(\frac{d[ J, A ]}{d[ A, B ]}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{d[ J, B ]}{d[ A, B ]}\right)^2 & 0 & \left(\frac{d[ J, K ]}{d[ A, B ]}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{d[ J, Q ]}{d[ A, B ]}\right)^2 & 1 & \\
  \left(\frac{d[ K, A ]}{d[ A, B ]}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{d[ K, B ]}{d[ A, B ]}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{d[ K, J ]}{d[ A, B ]}\right)^2 & 0 & \left(\frac{d[ K, Q ]}{d[ A, B ]}\right)^2 & 1 & \\
  \left(\frac{d[ Q, A ]}{d[ A, B ]}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{d[ Q, B ]}{d[ A, B ]}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{d[ Q, J ]}{d[ A, B ]}\right)^2 & \left(\frac{d[ Q, K ]}{d[ A, B ]}\right)^2 & 0 & 1 & \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \end{array}$.

Thus, the (normalized) Cayley-Menger determinants of distance ratios between any five elements of set $M$ vanishes; the metric space $(M, d \,)$ is flat. (However, the metric space $(M, d \,)$ is then still not necessarily plane, or even straight.)

The suitable assignment of real number triples $c_f$ to elements of any flat metric space, together with the described function $f$ therefore provides a good (scaled-isometric) representation of the given flat metric space.